# Comunicar funciones en extensión de chrome de popup.js y document.js

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, extensión-google-chrome, scope

Estoy desarrollando una extensión para usuarios de la comunidad donde uso un manifest que luce de la siguiente forma (V3):

```
    {
      "name": "gfhdhdfhfdh",
      "version": "1.0",
      "description": "gfhdhdfhfdh",
      "manifest_version": 3,
      "author": [
        {
          "author1": {
            "name": "gfhdhdfhfdh",
            "email": "gfhdhdfhfdh@gmail.com",
            "secction": "gfhdhdfhfdh"
          },
          "author2": {
            "name": "gfhdhdfhfdh",
            "email": "example@gmail.com",
            "secction": "Base Kit"
          }
        }
      ],
      "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      },
      "action": {
        "default_popup": "src/html/popup.html",
        "default_title": "gfhdhdfhfdh",
        "default_icon": {
          "32": "src/img/32.png",
          "48": "src/img/48.png",
          "64": "src/img/64.png",
          "128": "src/img/128.png"
        }
      },
      "icons": {
        "32": "src/img/32.png",
        "48": "src/img/48.png",
        "64": "src/img/64.png",
        "128": "src/img/128.png"
      },
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["https://*.com/*"],
          "js": ["src/js/document.js"],
          "css": ["src/css/style_links.css"],
          "run_at": "document_end"
        }
      ],
      "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "bookmarks",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage"
      ],
      "host_permissions": ["*://*/*"]
    }
```

el **popup.js** es donde estoy capturando la configuración deseada por el usuario; en teoría esta configuración será aplicada a la url actual abierta; por ahora tengo esto:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    
    let apply = document.getElementById('atsu-apply');
    let normal = document.getElementById('atsu-color-normal');
    let visited = document.getElementById('atsu-color-visited');
    let closed = document.getElementById('atsu-color-closed');

    normal.addEventListener("input", function (e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        IntefaceColor();
    });

    visited.addEventListener("input", function (e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        IntefaceColor();
    });

    closed.addEventListener("input", function (e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        IntefaceColor();
    });

});

function IntefaceColor(){
    let color_normal = document.getElementById('atsu-color-normal').value;
    let color_visited = document.getElementById('atsu-color-visited').value;
    let color_closed = document.getElementById('atsu-color-closed').value;
    
    console.log()
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({setcolor: [{normal:color_normal,visited:color_visited,closed:color_closed}]});
}
```

como pueden observas estoy tratando de llamar a `window.setColorLink` y me **da error por que no esta definido**, reconozco que es cierto... esta funcion en realidad esta en otro archivo `document.js` y este es su contenido:

```
console.log('document.js');
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message => {
    console.log(message);
    if (message.hasOwnProperty('setcolor')) {
        console.log(message);
        setColorLink(message.normal,message.visited,message.closed);
    }
});

function setColorLink(color_normal, color_visited, color_closed) {
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.setAttribute('id', 'atsu-style');
    style.innerHTML = `
                        a.question-hyperlink,
                        a.answer-hyperlink {
                            font-family: Calibri;
                            font-weight: 100;
                            font-style: italic;
                        }
                        
                        a.question-hyperlink,
                        a.answer-hyperlink {
                            color: `+ color_normal + `;
                        }
                        
                        a.question-hyperlink:visited,
                        a.answer-hyperlink:visited  {
                            color: `+ color_visited + ` !important;
                        }
                        `;

    var elementExists = document.getElementById("atsu-style");
    if (elementExists) {
        elementExists.innerHTML = style;
    } else {
        document.head.appendChild(style);
    }
    var links_questions = document.getElementsByClassName("question-hyperlink");
    var values = [].map.call(links_questions, function (element) {
        let herf = element.href;
        let title = element.innerHTML
        console.log(title);
        if (title.indexOf('[cerrada]') !== -1) {
            element.style.color = color_closed;
        }
    });
}
```

el objetivo de `setColorLink` es evaluar los anchor de la sitio actual abierto (no del popup de la extensión), y aplicarles un css especifico.

el problema es que no logro comunicas los archivos popup.js y document.js para que tengan el alcance de lo anterior descrito. si alguien me aclara esto y el ámbito de uso de `popup.js` y `document.js` y `background.js` se los agradecería, ya que no me quedo clara la documentacion en ingles.

**Actualización:**

pude determinar que de lado de la pestaña del navegador se ejecuta `document.js` y de lado de la extensión se esta ejecutando `popup.js` y `background.js`

entonces alguno de `popup.js` y `background.js` necesito que consuma una funcion de `document.js` y eso es lo que no logro hacer.

no logro que se ejecute; que en la medida que en el popup se cambian los colores; vaya cambiando los colores del link, en tiempo real.

Comment: El error es seguro por que llamas a un método de `window`, quita eso y prueba nuevamente

Comment: ok pero, drjame ver y pruebo...

Comment: ok, me avisas si funciona

Comment: @Christian nope no funciona sigo recibiendo: `Uncaught ReferenceError: setColorLink is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>` obviamente por que pertenecen a dos ventanas del navegador diferentes me imagino que son independiente pero entonces como las comunico XD...

Comment: @Christian hice una actualziacion resiente utilizando los listenes puedes verlos en el codigo del post estan actualizado pero no logro que se escuchen XD

Comment: Espera actualizo el github para que veas lo que hice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien dices, el `backgorund` y el `pop` se ejecutan aparte, vamos a llamarlo *"lado de la extensión"* y el `document.js` se ejecuta como un script más del sitio web.

La tarea de nosotros es comunicarnos desde el "lado de la extensión" hacia el `document.js`, esto se puede hacer de forma muy fácil gracias a los eventos.

En tu `popup.js` debes de enviar una petición que irá dirigido exclusivamente a tu `document.js` y esto se hace obteniendo el `id` del tab en el que es llamado el `popup` y luego de esto ya podemos enviar la información que queramos.

```js
async function IntefaceColor(){
    let color_normal = document.getElementById('atsu-color-normal').value;
    let color_visited = document.getElementById('atsu-color-visited').value;
    let color_closed = document.getElementById('atsu-color-closed').value;
    await chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, async function(tabs) {
      let tab = tabs[0]
      await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {"colors":[color_normal, color_visited, color_closed]});
    });
}
```

Con esto estamos enviando un objeto a la pestaña donde se ha abierto el `popup` ahora solo nos faltaría recibir y procesar esto en el `document.js` para eso debemos añadir un escuchador del evento `onMessage`

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(msg.colors){
       //haces lo que quieras
    }
});
```

Comment: esto fue lo que intebte solo me hace falta el async y el await... ahora que llego lo pruebo

Comment: lo siento se me había ido la luz y la respuesta no se publicó en el momento.

Comment: ya revise tu respuesta y me da esto: `Uncaught ReferenceError: browser is not defined` para esta linea:  `await browser.tabs`

Comment: trata con `chrome` en vez de `browser`

Comment: llega hasta donde se debe enviar el mensaje a `document.js` pero `document.js` no lo recibe tube que cambiar esto tambien para evitar el error: `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {` que es el listener pero no lo esta capturando XD

Comment: antes de cualquier cosa en el callback agrega `console.log(msg)`

Comment: es correcto por eso me doy cuenta que no llega XD

Comment: A! bueno no puedo replicar tu problema por que yo uso firefox. De igual ya actualicé el repo y puedes echarle un visto a la extensión

Comment: ya lo resolví solo tenia que refrescar el tab del navegador XD y usar chrome en los dos lados ... el problema es que no es compatible web extensión que es lo que tu usas vs Chrome extensión tienen diferencias pero se puede arreglar XD con alguas clausulas ternaria supongo ...

Comment: Haa... shap ._.